# RxAndroidBle2 sometimes loses notification with ble sensor when pairing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble, bluetooth-gatt

I created my own bluetooth service that manages ble sensors. I am having troubles when I try to pair new sensors. It connects successfully but when rxandroidble calls setCharacteristicNotification() and it returns `true` after less than one second it returns `enable: false`

Here is the logcat:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: false
```

so the sensor is connected but I can't get any data from that sensor.

Here is the code I use to start the service:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BluetoothTracker.class));
((User) getApplicationContext()).setServiceConnection(new ServiceConnection() {
     @Override
     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
         ((User) getApplicationContext()).setBluetoothTracker(((BluetoothTracker.MyLocalBinder) iBinder).getService());
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

     }
});
bindService(new Intent(this, BluetoothTracker.class), ((User) getApplicationContext()).getServiceConnection(), BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

When I start app this always works, only when I pair a new sensor I get this problem.

Here is the setupNotification function that seems to have the problem but I can't figure out what is happening

```
private static void setupNotify(RxBleConnection connection, UUID uuid, IGattCharacteristicHandler handler) {
    connection.getCharacteristic(uuid).subscribe(characteristic -> {
        Observable<byte[]> notification = connection.setupNotification(characteristic, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable);
        notification.subscribe(handler::handle, e -> Log.e(TAG, "BleException:" + e.getMessage()));
    }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "setupNotify::ERROR " + throwable.getMessage()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your connection lives till your observable has been completed.
you could implement onCompete callback and see how it happens.

rxandroidble handles connection termination automatically.
To get more details look at their [samples](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/tree/master/sample)